# How to repair corrupted Oracle export file (.dmp)?

Tags: oracle, file, dump, repair

I need to restore Oracle database from export file (.dmp) generated by EXP tool, but the file looks to be corrupted. Does anybody know a tool or solution to repair it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the error messages that lead you to believe that the file is corrupted to the question.

Comment: 1.ORA-39002: invalid operation
2.ORA-39059: dump file set is incomplete
3.ORA-39246: cannot locate master table within provided dump files,Could you please tell me which error show you

Comment: Sounds like there should be multiple dump files, not just one? What is the import command you are using, and what was the export command used if you have that? The export log might be useful too. (Add these to the question, not as comments, please).

Comment: Thanks for all replies. The dump file has been created by EXP tool and it is the single file (no parallel export). When trying to import it using IMP tools we have a bunch of errors like: `IMP-00003: ORACLE error 6550 encountered
ORA-06550: line 60, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
   := . ( @ % ;

IMP-00003: ORACLE error 2143 encountered
ORA-02143: invalid STORAGE option
IMP-00008: unrecognized statement in the export file: 
  ALTE

IMP-00003: ORACLE error 901 encountered
ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command`

Comment: If the file has somehow been truncated (partial copy somehow; interrupted transfer between servers? wrong transfer mode?) then it can't be repaired, the data just doesn't exist. Is this the original and only copy of the dump file, or can you get a fresh copy from somewhere?

Comment: It is the most recent copy of database. Previous good one in outdated.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the most helpful answer was deleted. Someone has suggested to use data recovery service for Oracle dump files provided by [Intelligent Converters](https://convert-in.com) and so I did. Indeed, they were able to repair my dump file. Our estimation is more than 95% of the data has been recovered. I hope this information will be useful for database people having similar problem.